# PHP How to call a function from another class and another file?

Tags: php, class

index.php

```
include('./class1.php');
include('./class2.php');

$Func = new function();
$Func->testfuncton1();
```

class1.php

```
class controller{

  public function test(){
    echo 'this is test';
  }
}
```

class2.php

```
class function{

  public function testfuncton1(){
    controller::test();
  }
}
```

But we not get content from function `test()`.

Tell me please where error ?

Comment: Please refer to my answer below...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issues:

- You CANNOT have a `class` named `function`. `function` is a `keyword`.
- You initialize `$Func`, but make call using `$Function`

If you remove these two issues, your code will work correctly:

```
class ClassController{

  public function test(){
    echo 'this is test';
  }
}

class ClassFunction{

  public function testfuncton1(){
    ClassController::test();
  }
}

$Func = new ClassFunction();
$Func->testfuncton1();
```

This should print `this is a test`

Comment: As ClassController::test() is not static it should be called from an instantiated object.

Comment: @vascowhite - Not necessarily. Non-static functions can be called using  `classname::function_name()` in php.

Comment: `You initialize $Func, but make call using $Function` - it was error in example

Comment: 2) name `function` - only for example

Comment: ["The Scope Resolution Operator is a token that allows access to __static__, __constant__, and __overridden__ properties or methods of a class."](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) test() is none of those, so shouldn't be called that way as far as I am aware. Where does the documentation say you can do it?

Comment: @vascowhite: Have you tried it, or only read documentation? :) Show me one version of PHP 5 where it will not work..Do not trust the documentation all the time :)

Comment: I generally go by the documentation. The fact that something undocumented works isn't something I would rely on, I guess the behaviour is undefined. YMMV.

Comment: @vascowhite - The basic distinction is `a property declared as static cannot be accessed with an instantiated class object` however a property that is *NOT* defined as static can be accessed in both ways.

Comment: @raidenace Your code raises a warning. http://3v4l.org/uLjCL#v513, so calling code that way is in-correct.

Comment: @vascowhite Yeah in 5.1 to 5.5 with strict standards. And in 5.6 without strict it is only deprecated (meaning legally it is correct to use, still...) Well,its all good that the OP got his issue resolved, if he runs into this problem of static, I am sure he will come back to SO with a new question :)